# auto_prepend_file multiple files

Tags: webserver, php

I'm trying to include multiple files *server wide*, so in `etc/php.ini` I have a few lines:

```
;Blowfish password
auto_prepend_file="/plugins/phpass-0.3/PasswordHash.php"

;WhoIs lookup
auto_prepend_file="/plugins/phpwhois-4.2.2/whois.main.php"

;IP database
;auto_prepend_file="/plugins/GeoIP/geoip.inc"
auto_prepend_file="/plugins/GeoIP/geoipcity.inc"
```

It would appear that only the last `auto_prepend_file` is being accepted, or it's overwriting the others.

How can I include multiple files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a separate loader file that require's the files you need, then prepend that file.

```
auto_prepend_file="/path/to/loader.php"
```

And in in loader.php:

```
require '/plugins/phpass-0.3/PasswordHash.php';
require '/plugins/phpwhois-4.2.2/whois.main.php';
require '/plugins/GeoIP/geoipcity.inc';
```

Comment: This is not exactly the same. Prepended files will fail with HTTP 500, whereas we cannot guarantee this behavior from `require` (require may spout rubbish to the user upon failing).

Comment: @Pacerier Prepended files fail with a 500 error when `display_errors` is _off_ and there is no output. This is the same when using `require`.